# How can I convert/export my mailing (a newsletter) into a PDF

Tags: activities

Please can you advise on the above. Can't seem to work it out!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE CiviCRM. When viewing the mailing you can click on print icon on top right corner. Which will pop up a screen to print, where you have an option to print as PDF. Other than this i don't see any option in CiviCRM to export the mailing into PDF

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Oops sorry I just posted an answer which was pretty much the same as yours. I should learn to read...

Comment: we will just vote pradeep's up higher :-)

Answer (score 1):

Possible option/solution –

Copy the HTML (source code) of your mailing

On any contact record, from the actions button, select Print/Merge Document

Paste the HTML source code into the Document Body field (Make sure you have selected to paste in source mode)

Click Download Document or Preview

This will allow you to create a PDF of your mailing.